# Filter table by start and end dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, daterangepicker

I have a table with information and they have dates like ex: '03-23-2019 00:00:00'

I want to add some filter by dates. I'm using Date Range Picker to get the calendar and select the dates.

As of now, I added two `<div>'s` to get the information (dates) that I want but now I'm having trouble to filter the table from that date to the other.

The table

```
  <div style="height: 300px;" class="card full-row redemptionsTab" id="locations-card">
        <h2>Redemptions</h2>

        <table class="redemptionData1" id="redeemptionsTable1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr class="table-header-row">
                <th>Coin/Reward</th>
                <th>Time</th>
                <th>Location</th>
                <th>User</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
```

The date picker

```
    <input type="text" class="datepickerInput" name="daterange" />
    <div style="display:none" class="startDate"></div>
    <div style="display:none" class="endDate"></div>
```

The logic to grab dates

```
$(function() {
    $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
      opens: 'left'
    }, function(start, end, label) {
      console.log("date selection " + start.format('YYYY-MM-DD') + ' to ' + end.format('YYYY-MM-DD'));

      let dateStart = $('.startDate').html(start.format('MM-DD-YYYY'))
      let dateEnd = $('.endDate').html(end.format('MM-DD-YYYY'))

    });

  });
```

Table Example
[image]

So now, I'm getting the dates on dateStart and dateEnd but I don't know how to filter with these. I've seen some examples online but none have helped me ;/

Any help would be amazing!!

Comment: BTW: This is a kludge. The best answer is to select by the date range in the server page where the appserver that is serving this is running

Comment: Its because I have another filters coming from the server side and if I add the date, they became dependent of each other, which I don't want, (I'm no expert on databases) , so this is why I decided to do it on the from end :/